# Would questions about the Bible be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In reference to this comment on Area 51:

> @AChildofGod Ah yes, sorry; that was a no to "Bible Answers" too. Incidentally, if you're looking for more of fact book for answers about the bible as a work of literature (as your example questions seem to suggest), we ***do*** have a site for **[Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)** where such questions properly phrased would be perfectly on topic. – Robert Cartaino♦ 1 hour ago

would questions about the Bible be on topic on this site?

Comment: While I was originally writing up an answer to this question, I've come to the conclusion that it's too broad as written to be properly addressed. There are a host of lenses that can be applied to the Bible, and the distinctions between them are rather stark. I think the topicality is going to depend very much on the question being asked. This isn't a "no," but I don't think it's a strict "yes," either. Did you have a _specific_ question in mind that you wanted to ask? If so, editing that into the question might give us a better sense of what you want and need.

Comment: If you do revise this question to ask about a particular question you want to ask, as @Emrakul recommended, consider using the [tag:specific-question] tag if appropriate.

Comment: @Emrakul I can understand that this question makes you apprehensive, [having been through this myself](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/why-was-this-question-about-the-old-testament-closed-as-off-topic), but I cannot find any reason why this question could possibly be considered too broad. Obviously the fact that a question is about topic X does not determine whether a question is good, that depends on the question being asked. But this meta question is about whether topic X (namely, the Bible) is on-topic. This is perfectly standard for a meta question.

Comment: Given that [we consider scientific papers to be on-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/717/are-questions-about-scientific-papers-on-topic-here), it would be hard to argue against religious texts being on-topic.

Comment: Please see [Should we allow questions about religious texts?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/186/11) TL; DR: yes, but when asking about literary aspects (whatever that means). There are sites like [christianity.se], [judaism.se], [buddhism.se], [hinduism.se], and [islam.se] that will provide better answers about the theological aspects.

Comment: To answer the question: yes, a question about the bible would be on-topic, go ahead and ask it. I'm looking forward to the question :)

Comment: Agreed with @Gilles on both counts: we should reopen this question and then close it as a dupe of [the existing question about religious texts](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/186/17). But short answer: YES, the Bible is on-topic (although naturally some questions about it wouldn't be). We even have [a tag for it](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-bible) and a few questions about it none of which have been closed.